# Comando imread() e iteração

Tags: python, opencv

Eu gostaria de fazer um laço com esse comando:

```
imagem = cv2.imread("imagens/0.jpg",0)
imagem = cv2.imread("imagens/1.jpg",0)
imagem = cv2.imread("imagens/2.jpg",0)
imagem = cv2.imread("imagens/3.jpg",0)
imagem = cv2.imread("imagens/4.jpg",0)
imagem = cv2.imread("imagens/5.jpg",0)
imagem = cv2.imread("imagens/6.jpg",0)
imagem = cv2.imread("imagens/7.jpg",0)
imagem = cv2.imread("imagens/8.jpg",0)
imagem = cv2.imread("imagens/9.jpg",0)
```

ao invés de repetir esse comando?
Estou utilizando opencv e o python.

Answer (score 0):

Já consegui resolver usando str() em uma concatenação:

```
for i in range(10):
    imagem = cv2.imread("imagens/"+str(i)+".jpg",0)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import os
import cv2

imagem_array = []

diretorio_pasta = "sua pasta de imagens aqui"

for imagem_dir in os.listdir(diretorio_pasta):
    try:
        imagem_array.append(cv2.imread(imagem_dir))
    except Exception as e:
        pass
```

Não cheguei a testar, mais e mais ou menos assim que se faz